# Insert a database dump with ruby-pg

Tags: ruby, postgresql, dump, psql

I have a database dump file with all sorts of insert statements and the occasional "\connect " command

The problem is that `PG::Connection.exec()` doesn't accept psql's `\`-commands like `\i` or `\c` etc.

Is there a way to use ruby-pg (or maybe another pg-gem) to do the job?

Since the database is on a different host I cannot use the Unix socket and therefore cannot connect as user `postgres` without password.

Comment: My answer is directly to the question, but I must ask on a more philosophical note:  If you cannot connect to the database to load a script and apparently cannot arrange to get it done by someone who can, *should* you be doing it in the first place. If you can't log into locally and you don't know the password, I would think you shouldn't be doing it.  Maybe it's a job for your DBA (or you need to get a better DBA).  Please don't mistake this for me being difficult, but the script should be loaded using psql.  Why you can't do that is a management problem, not a technical one.

Comment: Its a bit different. I'm the dba AND the unix admin.Thing is that I have to provide tools for people that are alot more unexperienced-customers decision. I've like a million tools written in shell that make my life easier.Including whole suites to failover and restore a whole bunch of unix systems and databases. So I hope I think that I know what I'm doing ;) I'm currently migrating the most of the shell stuff over to ruby because I want it testable and I want it to be easier to maintain. And I have made some twists in shell that I hope not to have to do in ruby. Including heavily nested cmds.

Comment: another thing & please don't get me wrong. I feel that I have to explain myself here. I maintain this systems (20 now with some nifty replication stuff going on) since the machines where first pulled into the data center. I'm the one knowing the systems inside out and I'm just trying to make my life easier. And yes it is a techn. problem. I'm just too lazy and my life too short to do everything by hand every day. Believe it or not, I can leave work after 8 hours because stuff is automated and working. Sry for trying to do stuff as effective as possible and therefore asking stupid questions

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to just use the psql command line tools like [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html):

```
pg_restore -d newdb db.dump
```

If you have ssh access to the box where the original database is hosted and know which table needs to be dumped, you can ssh into the box and directly pipe the [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) output to your local database. Something like:

```
ssh user@original_database pg_dump -U remote_user_name -T schema_name.table_name mydb | psql -U local_user_name -d local_database
```

Comment: Ya that would work but I was hoping to avoid that. As descibed above, I already use heavily nested commands that are hard to maintain in the shell script suites I'm migrating ruby for alot of reasons. I kind of thought about (as a last resort) to use a mixture of maybe Rye and piping through there or Open3. But I hoped it would be easier than that. I was hoping for a pg gem that is able to do that ^^

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no" as the backslash commands are NOT Postgres commands.  They are *psql* commands, which is the default command-line client.  No third-party tool will replicate these commands as they are not part of the *libpq* API.

Now, that said, is \connect the only backslash command in the file? If so, then you should be able to implement this by parsing out the database name from the \connect statement, then splitting the dump file into chunks starting with the first line after each \connect statement.  At that point, just run each chunk as normal against a connection to the database given in the \connect statement for that chunk.

As far as I know, there's no way to reconnect to a different database without creating a new connection since the user's credentials have to be re-validated.  That's even how psql does it behind the scenes.

There's one other thought, if there's only ONE \connect statement and it's immediately after a CREATE DATABASE statement which is immediately after statments like CREATE ROLE, then if you create the database as a separate step and remove both the CREATE DATABASE and \connect statements from the file, you MAY be able to do it without chunking.  Keep in mind that you'll still need two connections as you can't connect to a database before creating it and still can't change in mid-connection to a new database.

Comment: man that's all to unsatisfying. But it's easier and cleaner to strip the sql in two parts and do that. Making two (or more) sql connections wouldn't be a problem. It's (as written above) part of a rollback script that is executed if the system is down anyway. Well, never had to use the shell one I'm migrating to ruby and never hope that I have to use it after the ruby migration. But better be prepared for that one moment. I will consider this solution over the ones that are too "shellscripty" and that I already use. Okay, they work well. But they are a mess to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out alot of stuff including splitting the file at the \connect line, etc I ended up doint it the "old fashioned shell scripty way" for now ... the way that I wanted to avoid. But I have to get somewhere

What I'm doing now is the following:

```
  insert_command = "cat #{dump_file_path} | " +
        "ssh -p #{port} -i #{key} #{ssh_user}@#{db_host} " +
        "\"su - postgres -c 'cat > /tmp/rb_dump.sql && psql -f /tmp/rb_dump.sql ; rm /tmp/rb_dump.sql'\""

    Open3.popen3 insert_command do |stdin, stdout, stderr, t|
      unless t.value.to_s.include? "exit 0"
        <handle error>
      end
    end
```

It's totally hacky in my opinion, but it works ^^

My other solution would be the next code, which has a big problem (as stated below)

```
 def insert_database_dump(dump_file_handle, host, user, password, database = nil)
    begin
      pg = PG.connect(host: host, user: user, password: password, dbname: database)
      until dump_file_handle.eof?
        line = dump_file_handle.readline(";")
        if line =~ /connect\s(\w*)/
          line.gsub!("\\connect", "").strip!
          insert_database_dump(dump_file_handle, host, user, password, line)
        else
          pg.exec(line)
        end
      end
    ensure
      pg.finish unless pg.finished?
    end
  end
```

The code does the following (important parts only) :

- reads a line from the sql until ";" (the queries are split over several lines so reading just until the line break wont work
- execute the query
- if the line looks like "connect word", 'word' is selected as the database name and the method is called again with 'word' as the database name, and the current file handle which points to the correct line from which I want to proceed.

Despite the fact that there may be more elegant ways for a method to call itself, this works unless there are comments in the sql dump.
Problem is that the comments look like this:

```
-- foo: bar; bam: baz;
```

So when splitting with ";", it executes "-- foo: bar;", which works because it's a comment but fails with "bam: baz;"

I currently have no easy solution to remove the comment lines on the fly. So the Open3 solution will have to do until I find out.

Cheers,
 Stefan